# adding an int value to multi array int list

Tags: c#, list

I got this multiarray list of integers that would look something like this:

```
List<List<int>> multiarray = new() {    
    new() { 8, 63  },
    new() { 4, 2   }, 
    new() { 0, -55 }, 
    new() { 8, 57  }, 
    new() { 2, -120}, 
    new() { 8, 53  }
};
```

Now let's say I want to create it and add items using a variable, how will I do so?
I thought it would be as the following:

```
int value1 = 4
int value2 = 5
ListStat.Add(value1, value2);
```

But I get an error saying I cant overload using the method "add", any other command I should use?

Comment: What is `ListStat` and what do you expect the result of `ListStat.Add(value1, value2);` to be?

Comment: Can the inner list contain more than 2 items?

Comment: Assuming `ListStat` is `multiArray`: why not just do `multiArray.Add(new List { value1, value2 });` ?

Comment: If you mean what I think you mean and if `ListStat` is really `multiarray`, then what you want is similiar to what's in your list initializer: `multiarray.Add(new List<int>(value1, value2);`.  If the sub-lists will always have two members you might consider replacing them with a `Tuple<,>`, `ValueTuple<,>`, or custom class.

Answer (score 0):

As your list has the element type of `List<int>` and not `(int, int)`, you should **NOT** use `multiarray.Add((value1, value2)`, but instead use the following:

```cs
int value1 = 4;
int value2 = 5;
multiarray.Add(new List<int> { value1, value2 });
```

or, even shorter using [target-typed `new`-expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new):

```cs
multiarray.Add(new(){ value1, value2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

(Alternate method for problem solving, without multi List, but it's longer)

```
//Helper
record ListStat (int value1, int value2)

static void Main(string[] args)
{
      List<ListStat> lList = new List<ListStat>()
      {
           new ListStat(8,63),
           new ListStat(4,2),
           new ListStat(0,-55),
           new ListStat(8,57)
      };
      lList.Add(new ListStat(0, 0)); //Adding values
      Console.WriteLine($"({lList[0].value1};{lList[0].value2})"); //Ref to first element
      //Ref for all element step by step in lList
      foreach (ListStat singleItem in lList)
      {
          Console.WriteLine($"({singleItem.value1};{singleItem.value2})");
      }
}
```

Comment: This can shortened a lot by using `record` (e.g.: `record ListStat(int value1, int value2);` or a ValueTuple (e.g.:`(int value1, int value2)`) instead

Answer (score 0):

If your sublists are known to have only 2 items, I would strongly advise you to use [`ValueTuple<...>`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) instead of `List<int>`. This not only enhances the readability of your code, but also reduces your application's memory footprint and execution speed, as less memory has to be allocated and no append/adding-operations have to be executed for the sublists.

The readability is enhanced, as items such as `(1, 3)` are automatically interpreted as `ValueTuple<int, int>`.

The resulting code should look as follows:

```cs
List<(int, int)> multiarray = new() {    
    (8, 63  ),
    (4, 2   ), 
    (0, -55 ), 
    (8, 57  ), 
    (2, -120), 
    (8, 53  )
};
```

You may then add new items as follows *(notice the extra parenthesis)*:

```cs
multiarray.Add((value1, value2));
```

You can display your items as follows:

```cs
foreach ((int, int) tuple in multiarray)
      Console.WriteLine($"My list has the items ({tuple.Item1}, {tuple.Item2})");
```

or using the deconstruction-syntax:

```cs
foreach ((int value1, int value2) in multiarray)
      Console.WriteLine($"My list has the items ({value1}, {value2})");
```

---

You may also might want to name your tuple elements:

```cs
List<(int a, int b)> multiarray = new() {    
    (8, 63),
    (4, 2),
    ....
};
```

which allows you to use the following code:

```cs
int first = multiarray[0].a; // first tuple element of the first list item.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `List<T>` class has an `Add` method that takes a single value of type `T`. When you have a `List<List<T>>` then the `Add` member takes a single value of type `List<T>`. You are trying to add two values of type `T` and the compiler doesn't know what to do with them.

If you want you code to work as is, then you can add an extension method to make it work.

Try this:

```
public static class MyListExtensions
{
    public static void Add<T>(this List<List<T>> listList, params T[] items)
    {
        listList.Add(new List<T>(items));
    }
}
```

Now your code works just fine:

```
List<List<int>> ListStat = new()
{
    new() { 8, 63 },
    new() { 4, 2 },
    new() { 0, -55 },
    new() { 8, 57 },
    new() { 2, -120 },
    new() { 8, 53 }
};

int value1 = 4
int value2 = 5
ListStat.Add(value1, value2);
```